# Maximum value of a tuple

Tags: python

I've this tuple:

```
lpfData = ((0.0, 0.0), (0.100000001490116, 0.0879716649651527), ..., (1.41875004768372, 0.481221735477448),..., (45.1781234741211, 0.11620718985796))
```

and I want to find the maximum value of the second column. So I use:

```
maxLPFt = max(lpfData)
maxLPF = maxLPFt[1]
```

But I get always the value of the second column coupled with the maximum value of the first column. Basic stuff but google didn't help.

Cheers

Joao

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a function as `key` argument to extract the value you want to compare<sup>†</sup>:

```
import operator
maxLPFt = max(lpfData, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

This will use the second element of each tuple for the calculation.

**Reference**: [`max`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max), [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

---

†: Similar to how `sort` and `sorted` work, that's why the information in the [Sorting HowTo](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) might be relevant as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to tack onto Felix Kling's answer, which I can't thank you enough for, if you would like to single out a max number in the tuple, add ['index'] on to the end of Felix Kling's code.  For my application I needed the max number which resided in the second index of each tuple.  My code was:

```
maxLPFt = max(lpfData, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]
```